# Declaring a variable inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this problem when i declare a variable inside a function it tells me that the variable is declared but it's value is never read and when i try to use this variable again it's undefined and i tried different text editors and it's the same problem 
[the functions that i want the variable to be define in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK7mO.png)

[image]

[image: the error that came out]

Comment: when are you planning to assign value in this variable ?

Comment: The variable only exists in the scope of that function. If you want the variable to be available everywhere put `var random;` outside the function.

Comment: Also, the error you shared in screenshot is __not an error__ , its a warning which can be ignored

Comment: @AmanChhabra  Is correct, it's a warning, you have declared a var called random, and don't use it..   But I wouldn't say `can be ignored`. :),   you might have just meant to do -> `return math.floor(.....` instead.

Comment: it's already have  value and i will use this value to generate random number

Comment: @Keith agreed... basically there are lot many errors in the code. For instance, I think OP want to use __pickedColor__ instead of __randomColor__ in __generateRandomColors__

Comment: but when i tried to access it's value in if statement  inside this function it didn't work

Comment: In which function.... generateRandomColors ? If yes, then you need to either increase the scope of random or return it from pickedColors

Comment: in functions pickedColors and  generateRandomColors  When i use it in anther area i doesn't do what it is supposed to do it doesn't work

Comment: I tried to explain this in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482592/1262248

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it is a warning to inform the developer that some more work needs to be required to use that variable. It **won't stop** the execution of your code.

Though, definitely it needs to be taken care and below are possible options to remove this error:

1) return random from pickedColor function

```js
var colors = {
  "length": 200
};

function pickedColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}

function generateRandomColors(nums) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    arr.push(pickedColor());
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(generateRandomColors(8));
```

2) increase the scope of random variable

```js
var colors = {
  "length": 200
};
var random = 0;

function pickedColor() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}

function generateRandomColors(nums) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    pickedColor()
    arr.push(random);
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(generateRandomColors(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is occurring because you're not **returning** anything from *pickedColor()*. You create the *random* variable, but it's not returned. Thus when you try to use the function, you're getting *undefined*. This can be fixed by adding a return to the *pickedColor()* function:

```
function pickedColor(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}
```